# mongoose db - array insertion using create and save

Tags: arrays, node.js, insert, mongoose

How to insert array and normal variable data to mongoose database..

```
var parent = new Parent({ children: [{ name: 'Matt' }, { name: 'Sarah' }], class: 10 })
parent.save(callback);
```

This is the method i know currently.
I need it to be done from the req.body. So how can I done after creating the parent object. ie

```
var parent =  new Parent();
///code for inserting the array data and other normal datatypes 
parent.save(callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the document instance like any other javascript object.

```
parent.children = [{ name: 'Matt' }, { name: 'Sarah' }];
parent.class = 10;
parent.save();
```

Just don't change it entirely (like doing `parent = {...}`), otherwise you'd have de-referenced the actual mongoose document instance. Only make changes on its properties like shown above.